# Gravity Forms - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to edit the gravity forms using javascript. When I submit a form whether or not it's successful or has errors the page makes an immediate jump to the top of the form. Is it possible to remove this action and make the transition smoother?

I found an event that gets run on form render, but I can't figure out how to remove the behaviour.

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's annoying isn't it!
Have you tried this post found on Gravity Forms support?
http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_confirmation_anchor

Comment: Haha! Thanks Darren, this should help.